# drive pdf app shows download option even file is downloaded

Tags: android, pdf

My android app downloads pdf file from web service via get method and url is https. After downloading it sends the file to drive pdf app to open the file. Drive app opens the file correctly but there is something weird. On top right menu there is a download option. When I click it drive app try to download the file and file gets broken. Never open it again. Drive app says: "**invalid type**". Why drive pdf app shows download option even the file is downloaded? Is there a way to hide it?

Edit: My piece of code that opens drive app is;

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
        intent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "application/pdf");
    } else {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.setData(uri);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    }
```

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear. By the way my device version is 7.0

Answer (score 0):

If this pdf you are downloading via GET method I am assuming is not from drive. You are firing an intent to open that pdf via drive. The pdf opened on your drive viewer is not uploaded(exists) on your drive. Now when you click the download option it shows up on notification as that pdf as downloaded which it does not(it just shows up as notification I don't know why this happens it might be a bug in drive viewer maybe). and hence when you click on the notification it shows you the error as invalid type because no such file is downloaded(it like an empty intent).

The download option shown in drive viewer is a default and will show up in every pdf you open from drive viewer.

Also, there is no way to hide that button as it is in drive app and not yours.

Also, I did the exact steps and also get the same error.

Comment: Yes that's true i'm downloading from my app then open it via drive. But pls check this mini article http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/02/21/psa-google-drive-can-now-open-pdf-files-directly-without-downloading-them-first/ . Download option is gone when the file link is https. But perhaps it's about downloading from drive. I'm not sure.

Comment: I would like to also add that it actually does download the file.If you check your downloads folder you will see a pdf with the same name just with size 0 bytes. Clicking and opening in drive viewer close it immediately as there is no data in it.

Comment: I've tested your case. I've downloaded a pdf file from my drive. Then in file explorer I opened with drive pdf viewer and unfortunately same. On right top menu there is download option and after click it file got broken

Comment: Also, the behavior of http vs https as said in the article is only an observation. 
This behavior is also reproducible in google pdf viewer which is separately provided on playstore.Link :https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.pdfviewer&hl=en

Comment: Yess..same behaviour with Google Pdf Viewer.. Its really hard to understand why download option exist even file is downloaded :)

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as accepted so others looking for an unanswered question don't end up here.

Comment: Sorry but i'm not satisfied from answer. Said just did the exact steps. Waiting for more useful answer that I can accept it.